# Interactive Python Script to run commands on remote server

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I need to write a script to ssh to remote server and run some commands there.
Can anyone suggest me any modules that will help me do this?

I tried to use pexpect. I was able to login to machine, provide password, but could not execute any unix commands.
Is pexpect meant for this sort id usage?

```
command = 'ssh '+'uname@'+ vm

    ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
    # my ssh command line
    p=pexpect.spawn(command)

    i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
    if i==0:
        print "Say yes to prompt"
        p.sendline('yes')
        i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
    if i==1:
        print "I give password\n",
        p.sendline("abcd")
        p.sendline("pwd")
        p.expect('xyza')
        #p.sendline("//some unix command")
```

Everything until the last line is ok, but there onwards my script just exits.

Comment: `paramiko.SSHClient` that is all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something relatively quick on a remote server [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) is probably the best thing to use for python. Fabric is written on top of paramiko and has some API level abstraction that makes it easier to use than paramiko.